# How can I print only displayed/visible/(shown on the screen) text contents of any website using python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath

I want to print/get only visible text content {currently what the user is seeing} from any website.

I tried using multiple approaches and I am getting all the texts from the page but not the intended texts.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options) #'CustomerProject-createCustomerProject&/Create'
url = "https://techcrunch.com/"
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(r"//body")
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerText", element)
```

Is there any way to get only visible texts.

Note: If the solution is pure javascript, more than welcome.

Comment: Why are you spam tagging a [tag:javascript] here, i removed it

Comment: if you see the code
driver.execute_script()
it takes javascript code, i think javascript is the only way to get the result.

Comment: But that's not uncommon in selenium, so that's why only 731 questions have [tag:python] [tag:javasript] [tag:selenium] tags, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+javascript+selenium)

Comment: Can you share your use case ?

Comment: Thanks all, for your support.
I found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Get the `body` element and use the `.text` method to get the text of that element.

Try this:

```py
driver.get("https://techcrunch.com/")
element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
print(element.text)
```

---

If you are guessing that `(opens in a new window)` text is not visible in the document but present in the result that is because it is present on the page. If you try `Ctrl + A` and copy the text you would get the same result. You can even search for the text in the page using `Ctrl+F`.

The reason you are not seeing the text is that it is clipped using `webkit-clip-path`.

> The clip-path CSS property creates a clipping region that sets what part of an element should be shown. Parts that are inside the region are shown, while those outside are hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Still, that will give the entire text content, i want just the content which is visible to the user.
There are contents, which is visible after scrolling, that is also printing using this method, which i don't intend

Comment: Find which CSS classes are visible and which ones are not. Filter content according to that information.

Comment: The `element.text` is getting the visible text of the page. What part do you think it is showing extra that javascript won't show?

Comment: i ran the code on this page, i am getting texts from top "stack overflow" to bottom "site design / logo.."
here we can only see the footer after scrolling down, which is not currently visible but still printing, which i don't want.

Comment: Both of the text you mentioned is visible on the page and inside the body tag. That means the code is doing what it supposed to do. Now if you are trying to get text, not from the whole page but only the part is shown on screen at the moment without scrolling then that is an entirely different question. But to the browser the whole scrollable page is visible.

Comment: Thanks.

I want the part which is shown on the screen, as I think the question is a little confusing, I will modify the question title.